# Eclipse CDT automatically replace "." with "->"

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-cdt

The Qt Creator have a neat feature I really like. When I'm typing `obj.method`, it would automatically replace the period (`.`) with an arrow (`->`), if `obj` is a pointer.

Makes sense actually. You never want to type `pointer.something`, it wouldn't be legal.

Is there a way to achieve a similar function with Eclipse CDT?