# Is there a way in Eclipse CDT to automatically switch from . to ->

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The Qt Creator have a neat feature I really like. When I'm typing obj.method, it would automatically replace the period (.) with an arrow (->), if obj is a pointer.

Makes sense actually. You never want to type pointer.something, it wouldn't be legal.

Is there a way to achieve a similar function with Eclipse CDT?

This question is a duplicate from an old one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630711/eclipse-cdt-automatically-replace-with) but i also miss that function and i'm not sure that a comment to that question will "bump" it.

Comment: I'd say it's a bad habit - if ever you change the IDE or work in vim/np++/..., you'll waste all the time you saved by typing 2 chars instead of one on fixing the compilation errors. "clever" editor is not a replacement to Java... ;)

Comment: ooops - should be "typing one char instead of 2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upcoming CDT 8.0 for Eclipse Indigo has that feature.

Comment: How do you use that feature, im on indigo but I haven't seen it do that. Sounds cool